# C# File Iteration Issue

Tags: c#, .net, mailmessage

```
string line;
int counter = 0;

do
{
    line = readFile.ReadLine();
    counter++;

    var emailAddress = line;

    if (line != null)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Reading client email address...");
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myEmailAddress");
        mailMessage.To.Add(line);
        mailMessage.Subject = "TEST_SUBJECT";
        mailMessage.Body = "TEST_BODY";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mailMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("Email sent to: " + line);
    }

} while (line != null);
```

The problem is, whenever the app sends an email, it iterates again trough the source (the file where are stored the emails) and it goes like:
Read lines > Send email to line 1 > Read lines > Send email to line 1 & line 2 > Read lines > Send emails to line 1, 2 & 3 and so on. It doesn't go like it's supposed to: Read lines > Send email to line 1 > Send email to line 2.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the code you've shown will do that. Please show a short but complete program and a sample input file. (The program doesn't need to send emails of course - just write console output.) Note that using a `foreach` loop over `File.ReadLines` would be simpler.

Comment: It seems you do client.Send(mailMessage); each cycle while mailMessage.To.Add(line); looks like its storing whole list of recipients. Try creating new intance of mailMessage on begining of each cycle or clearing list of recipients for quick fix, to see if it works.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2li2bu This is the output, here, it kinda goes right.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(line);
```

With each iteration, you ADD anoter email address to the message, wich causes your problem.

try something like:

```
mailMessage.To.Clear();
mailMessage.To.Add(line);
```

or initialize a new mailMessage object in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should init mailMessage with new in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the line:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(line);
```

You are adding a new recipient to the message, but not getting rid of old ones from previous iterations.

Assuming you're using [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage), [To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to) is a [MailAddressCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection) type so you should be able to clear old entries using:

```
mailMessage.To.Clear();
```

Comment: How to get rid of the old entries from the previous iteration?

Comment: Edited my answer - see above.